# Handle ping exceptions/errors in C#

Tags: c#, string, exception, ping

I'm not sure if it's possible to checck before starting to ping since how could the program tell if it's a valid hostname or not?
The problem is that the Ping(); can return with various errormessages and I only want to determine if the answer is either:
 - "Ping request could not find host HOSTNAME. Please check the name and try again." So if the hostname doesn't exists at all,
 - There is a "Reply from" so if the pc is on,
 - "Destination host unreachable." so if there is a hostname like that but it's offline,
 - if there is any other error.
This isn't working very well for me for some reason.

```
            try
            {
                var address = Dns.GetHostEntry(inputText.Text).AddressList.First();

                string returnMessage = string.Empty;
                PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions(128, true);
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(address, 1000, buffer, pingOptions);
                        if (!(pingReply == null))
                        {
                            switch (pingReply.Status)
                            {
                                    break;
                                case IPStatus.TimedOut:
                                    returnMessage = "Connection has timed out...";
                                    break;
                                default:
                            returnMessage = string.Format("Ping failed: {0}", pingReply.Status.ToString());
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            returnMessage = "Connection failed for an unknown reason...";
                    }
                    catch (PingException ex)
                    {
                        returnMessage = string.Format("Connection Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                    }
                    catch (SocketException ex)
                    {
                        returnMessage = string.Format("Connection Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException f)
            {
                //errormessage here
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                //errormessage here
            }
```

Or is this actually handeling all the cases such as hostname not found, offline, online, other errors? It would just be great to know if which case/error/exception is which.
Thank you!

Comment: Is there some invisible force that is preventing you to read the documentation?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipstatus(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you have already case IPStatus.TimedOut, why not using the others ?